# Steam for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, steam, bumblebee

I'm a new member of Ubuntu 16.04. I installed Steam to Play Cs:Go but it's running with intel GPU. I installed bumblebee but it's not working i guess. So, should i install 14.04 or is there any solution to play Cs:Go?

And of course if there's a solution, please tell me how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You should install and use nvidia propreitary drivers, there's no need to use bumblebee for 16.04.

First, open terminal and remove bumblebee:

```
sudo apt-get remove bumblebee
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, add nvidia driver PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally, install nvidia drivers of your choice, nvidia-364 is the last version currently.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-364
```

After doing this, reboot your computer and you can change the GPU from intel to nvidia by running

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

After you done playing, you can go back to using intel GPU by

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

PS: I'm not sure if it automatically changes GPU when you start playing games, it was when I was playing with 14.04.

---

If you encounter any login loop problems (having to enter password endlessly and couldn't login) then you should ctrl+alt+f1 and login with your login credentials there and run

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

Cheers.